# How to copy *.txt files recursevely in another destination?

Tags: linux

i need to copy all txt files included in a lot of subdirectories into a single directory.
Example:

```
 MyDir
   Dir1
     1.txt
     2.txt
   Dir2
     a.txt
     b.txt
     e.jpg
   Dir3 
     f.txt
     k.txt
  MyDestination
```

How to copy all txt to MyDestination ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using find ...

```
find /MyDir -name '*.txt' -exec cp -t /MyDestination "{}" +
```

which will find the relevant txt files and pass them in batches to cp to have it copy them to MyDestination.

Answer (score 0):

What about

`cp -R *.txt <destination>`

Comment: This won't work because the `*.txt` is expanded by the shell, not by `cp`. This will copy any top level .txt files as well as recursively copy any top level **directories** which match `*.txt`.